# Union Two Running Balance in SQL

Tags: sql-server

When i execute these queries  Individually , Running Total and Running Average comes right but after union  Running Total and Running Average is not calculating right.

Cant understand what is happening in union.

```
 SELECT BillDate,Location,Branch,Quantity,Amount,NoOfTransaction,BillYear,Item, 
    SUM(Amount) over(order by BillDate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal,
    AVG(Amount) over(order by BillDate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningAverage
    FROM vwLocationWiseSales
    WHERE  YEAR(BillDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())

    UNION

    SELECT BillDate,Location,Branch,Quantity,Amount,NoOfTransaction,BillYear,Item, 
    SUM(Amount) over(order by BillDate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal,
    AVG(Amount) over(order by BillDate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningAverage
    FROM vwLocationWiseSales
    WHERE YEAR(BillDate) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()))
```

Sample Data

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Bahadurabad - Floor                                9.248                                   3782.71                                 4               2015        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Binori Town - Floor                                5.560                                   2298.27                                 4               2015        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Boat Basin-Floor                                   1.634                                   678.11                                  2               2015        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Phase 2 Commercial-Floor                           17.374                                  5994.03                                 17              2016        CHICKEN KARHAI CUT ( 18 PIECES )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            SEHER - Floor                                      6.142                                   3249.12                                 7               2016        CHICKEN MINCE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            SEHER - Floor                                      0.006                                   2.02                                    1               2016        WHOLE CHICKEN
```

Required OutPut

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Bahadurabad - Floor                                9.248                                   3782.71                                 4               2015        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   3782.71                                 
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Binori Town - Floor                                5.560                                   2298.27                                 4               2015        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6080.98                                 
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Boat Basin-Floor                                   1.634                                   678.11                                  2               2015        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6759.09                                 
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            Phase 2 Commercial-Floor                           17.374                                  5994.03                                 17              2016        CHICKEN KARHAI CUT ( 18 PIECES )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                5994.03                            
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            SEHER - Floor                                      6.142                                   3249.12                                 7               2016        CHICKEN MINCE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   9243.15                            
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 CHICKEN                                            SEHER - Floor                                      0.006                                   2.02                                    1               2016        WHOLE CHICKEN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   9245.17
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using one query instead:

```
SELECT BillDate, Location, Branch, Quantity, Amount, NoOfTransaction, 
       BillYear,Item, 
       SUM(Amount) over(partition by YEAR(BillDate)
                        order by BillDate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal,
       AVG(Amount) over(partition by YEAR(BillDate)
                        order by BillDate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningAverage
    FROM vwLocationWiseSales
    WHERE  YEAR(BillDate) IN (YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())),  YEAR(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'., can you please correct it

Comment: still same issue, running balance of first year is calculating right, but running balance of second year coming wrong

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq Can you post some sample data so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have added the sample data